# Waiting for JavaScript event with Selenium

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, browser-automation

I am building an automation framework on top of Selenium (Node.js) consisting on a number of steps.
Each step follows the previous one, after it completes, returning a promise (like the one returned by Selenium's driver.click(), etc).
Is it possible to wait for a JavaScript event to trigger on the browser? If so, what is the pattern to follow?

Comment: do you mean wait until your java script fully executed and returned using selenium?

Comment: No, I meant what I said: wait for a JavaScript event to trigger. Waiting for a script to execute is trivial using driver.executeScript().

Comment: For example, I would like to inject window.onmessage = function() { ... continue with the node.js promise chain ... }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.executeAsyncScript` to wait for an event to occur :

```
driver.executeAsyncScript(function(callback) {
  window.addEventListener('message', function onmessage() {
    window.removeEventListener('message', onmessage);
    callback();
  });
});
```

The doc:

http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver_exports_WebDriver.html#executeAsyncScript